# Black screen instead of video background on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, divi

Video background from site header not showing on iPhone. I read that need to specify attributes, but they were already there except of 'preload'. Ive just added all necessary attributes additionaly, but it did not help :(

This code Ive added.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var video_header = $('video');
  video_header.prop('preload','auto');
  video_header.prop('autoplay','true');
  video_header.prop('loop','loop');
  video_header.prop('playsinline','playsinline');
  video_header.prop('webkit-playsinline','');
  video_header.prop('muted','true');
});
</script>
```

Btw, chrome dev tools on Iphone 12 pro display everything.

[image]

```
<video loop="" autoplay="" playsinline="" muted="" preload="auto" id="mejs_5217348005770652_html5" src="https://suik.online/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/50-mb.webm" style="margin: 0px; width: 390px; height: 780px;">
<source type="video/webm" src="https://suik.online/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/50-mb.webm">
</video>
```

[Web-site](https://suik.online/)

Thanks for any help.

To see it work on an iPhone

Comment: Have you first of all verified, whether that browser can play your video at all? You appear to be using the webm format only, and that comes with some restrictions when it comes to iPhone's Safari, it can only play specific variants: https://caniuse.com/webm

Comment: Probably you're right, brother. I uploaded mp4 and everything went well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, WebM video playback is **not available on iPhone.** If you want to play WebM files on iPhone, you need to have mp4 file format as well.

Comment: It's a pity, mp4 weighs 4 times more.